# Getting higher power output by using more resistors

Tags: resistors

Is there anyway I can connect resistors to allow them to take more power such as using 4 1/4 watt resistors to get a 1 watt resistors. Or do i just have to use 1 1 Watt resistor.

Comment: related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12179/is-parallelling-inductors-a-viable-solution

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can use (4) 0.25 W resistors to dissipate 1 W and still remain within each individual resistor's power rating.  This can be accomplished a few different ways:

- Place them all in **series**:

  - In which case you will need to use resistors with **1/4 the resistance** that you want overall.
  - e.g. If you want 1 kΩ total, put (4) 250 Ω (240 Ω nearest 5% standard) resistors in series.
- Place them all in **parallel**:

  - In which case you will need to use ones with **4 times** the overall desired resistance
  - e.g. If you want 1 kΩ total, put (4) 4 kΩ (3.9 kΩ nearest std.) resistors in parallel.
- Placing them in a **2x2 array**:

  - Where you can use resistors of the **same resistance** you want overall (2 in parallel gives half, but you place 2 sets of parallel in series, doubling the effective resistance)

In all the mentioned cases, in order to have each resistor dissipate an equal share of power, they all must be equal in value (ohms).  This isn't the *only* way to do it, there are several other combinations you could use with differing values, etc.

Pragmatically, if you're only operating this circuit very intermittently (few seconds at a time), you *might* be able to get away with a single 1/4 W resistor, especially if this is on a breadboard (be careful not to melt stuff).  Higher power resistors often are specified to survive surges of 8-10x their normal power dissipation for several seconds, though the typical 1/4 W thru-hole resistors are carbon film, which is a little less tolerant of this.

Comment: Beaten to the punch! ;)

Comment: +1 especially for the 2x2 array, which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @mskfisher, for every chain in parallel you should add one in series. 3X3 or 4X4, the divide factor is 1/N so you need N in a row to cancel it out.

Comment: For higher reliability, with four components in series, if any one fails, they all fail, which multiplies your risk, but also might be what you want (working or non-working).  With four components in parallel, if one component fails, the circuit might still work acceptably (or it might be a bad thing).  But, the more components you spread the wattage out with, the smaller the change if one fails.

Comment: Additionally, the "super-component" 2x2 array pattern also works with capacitors and inductors, and extends to 3x3, 4x4, and any other N-by-N square array.

Comment: Finally, I've met my power and inductance requirements with two inductors in series so that I could meet a 4.5mm height limitation for which I could not find a single component.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD be careful about how you're placing the inductors then (especially if not shielded, and even then might want to validate it a bit) so you don't have stray coupling that lowers the effective inductance.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, putting them in parallel increases the group power dissipation and lowers group resistance. You still need to calculate power dissipation separately.

$$R1 \parallel R2 = \frac{R_{1}R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}$$

$$P = IV = I^{2}R = \frac{V^{2}}{R}$$

If you have N resistors in parallel and they are all the same value, power dissipation will be N-times their individual rating and group resistance will be 1/N times their individual rating.