# What are the issues with using multiple inductors for a DC/DC converter?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, inductor, buck

I'm going to be designing a Buck Converter that will supply a max of 10A of current to an LED Strip (9V to 20V in, 5V out). Since I want to minimize the amount of EMI in the circuit, I want to use shielded inductors rated for around 26uH. But since the inductor would have to be rated for at least 10A (preferably 15A or higher), there aren't a lot of options to chose from. So instead, I was thinking of using two 13uH inductors in series so that I would have a larger variety of parts.

I understand that the math works out to where 13uH + 13uH = 26uH. But are there any real world issues that comes with using multiple inductors in a DC/DC converter?

Comment: I was also considering doing this, so I would very much like an answer to this. Other reasons to do this might include hight or other dimensional limitations. Can you clarify that the inductors are the same, and that they should be right next to each other, connected with a very short, low-resistance connection? My guess would be, if there were a tricky problem, it might be in the parasitics and how they produce ringing. Layout may be trickier than usual. You might also consider parallel configuration. Also, keep in mind that resistance also doubles. Have simulated this in boost w/o troubles.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Throw in parasitic caps of different values in parallel with your inductors in simulation. Different for each inductor.

Comment: @DKNguyen -- Have done. Put 3 Taiyo Yuden NRS6010T100MMGF 10uH 1.1A 324mOhm SMD  in series with 100p on 1st, 71p on 2nd, & 120p on 3rd. Ringing max 12mA. Doesn't seem to affect output. What should I be seeing?

Comment: I was just curious how much is too much is all. If the resonant frequency of the tank circuit matches one of the switching harmonics I would expect to see an increase in noise at that frequency. Just like with anti-resonance when mixing decoupling caps.

Comment: The shielded capacitance of the choke  will resonate more Amps than an unshielded choke. Better to put a shield over the SMPS than use a shielded choke

Comment: I would try to use parallel inductors instead.

Comment: @fraxinus -- Why do you say to use parallel instead?

Comment: There is a good answer here: **[Is parallelling inductors a viable solution? -- yes, suggest trying a super-inductor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/12399/146624)**, where it talks about a "super-inductor", an array of 2x2 (4 total) inductors that have the same inductance and resistance, but much greater saturation ability, because the currents are divided. In other words, each inductor actually has the same saturation limit, but because the currents are divided, a 2x2 array of the same inductor can handle twice the saturation current.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD We need your winding polarity comment that was on the other question on here as an answer.

Comment: @Jay, did you ever try, and hopefully verify this? I'm thinking of doing the same due to height constraints. After coming here I don't feel the thought was *too* crazy...

Answer (score 2):

If you use identical inductors I see no real issues except for minor resonances since parts are never identical.